# How can I use "cached" consistency for named volumes with docker swarm mode / improve io performance on osxfs?

Tags: macos, caching, docker-swarm, docker-volume

I am trying to set up a development stack as similar as possible to the docker swarm production deployment. Unfortunately some members of the team prefer to work on osx which has severe performance issues when it comes to mounting and syncing of volume data with osxfs. I came across the a [docker blog entry](https://blog.docker.com/2017/05/user-guided-caching-in-docker-for-mac/) about **consistency setting "cached"** for a docker-compose setup on mac, e.g.:

```
volumes:
  - /www:/var/www:cached
```

This **does not work in swarm mode** however. I am getting following **error on `docker stack up`**:

```
invalid spec: webapp-volume:/var/www:cached: unknown option: cached
```

**Is this an option that was removed for v3, supposed to be used differently, or is there a better way to improve io performance on osx with swarm mode?**

Comment: If you check the documentation this is not supported by `docker-compose` as such. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes. It only lists `:ro` as the option